# Spark scala partition dataframe for large cross joins

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, cross-join

I have two dataframes that need to be cross joined on a 20-node cluster. However because of their size, a simple crossjoin is failing. I am looking to partition the data and perform the crossjoin and am looking for an efficient way to do it.

### Simple Algorithm

Manually split file f1 into three and read into dataframes: `df1A, df1B, df1C`. 
 Manually split file f2 into four and ready into dataframes: `df2A, df2B, df2C, df2D`.
 Cross join `df1A X df2A, df1A X df2B,..,df1A X  df2D,...,df1C X df2D`. 
Save each cross join in a file and manually put together all files. 
This way Spark can perform each cross join parallely and things should complete fairly quickly.

### Question

Is there is more efficient way of accomplishing this by reading both files into two dataframes, then partitioning each dataframe into 3 and 4 "pieces" and for each partition of one dataframe cross join with every partition of the other dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data frame can be partitioned ether range or hash .

```
val df1 = spark.read.csv("file1.txt")

val df2 = spark.read.csv("file2.txt")

val partitionedByRange1 = df1.repartitionByRange(3, $"k")
val partitionedByRange2 = df2.repartitionByRange(4, $"k")

 val result =partitionedByRange1.crossJoin(partitionedByRange2);
```

NOTE : set property  spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled=true

Comment: How would I get access to each partition so I can loop on each partition?

Answer (score -1):

You can convert this in to a rdd and then use cartesian operation on that RDD. You should then be able to save that RDD to a file. Hope that helps